# This one is definitely going to be harder! (Binary?)

Tags: cipher

here you go? This is a LOT to decode
3036302030363120303630203036312030363020303631203036312030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303630203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303630203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303630203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036312030363020303630203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303630203036312030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303630203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303630203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303631203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303631203036312030363120303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303630203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303631203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363120303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303630203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303430203036302030363120303630203036302030363120303631203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303630203036312030363020303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303630203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303630203036302030363120303631203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303630203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303430203036302030363120303630203036302030363020303631203036302030363120303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303630203036312030363120303630203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303630203036302030363020303631203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303630203036312030363020303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363120303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363120303630203036302030363120303430203036302030363020303630203036302030363120303630203036312030363020303430203036302030363120303630203036312030363120303631203036312030363020303430203036302030363020303630203036302030363120303630203036312030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303631203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303631203036312030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303630203036312030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303630203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303630203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303630203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036312030363120303430203036302030363020303630203036302030363120303630203036312030363020303430203036302030363020303630203036302030363120303630203036312030363020303430203036302030363020303630203036302030363120303630203036312030363020303430203036302030363020303630203036302030363120303630203036312030363020303430203036302030363020303630203036302030363120303630203036312030363020303430203036302030363020303630203036302030363120303630203036312030363020303430203036302030363020303630203036302030363120303630203036312030363020303430203036302030363120303630203036302030363120303630203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036312030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363120303630203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303631203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303631203036302030363120303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303630203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036302030363120303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036302030363120303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363120303630203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036302030363120303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303630203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303630203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303630203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303630203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303630203036312030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036312030363020303631203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036302030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303631203036312030363120303430203036302030363120303631203036302030363120303631203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363020303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036302030363120303630203036302030363020303430203036302030363020303631203036312030363120303630203036312030363020303430

Comment: i bet some people looked and was like Im outta here

Comment: This looks a lot like most people would be TL;DR here. What are users supposed to do?

Comment: Hi Dcybroz :) To understand the overall reaction to this puzzle it might be worth having a read of [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717/60644). Codes without any background tend not to be a lot of fun, as there's no hook to help a puzzler know where to begin. No sneaky clues, no helpful information - it's like a needle in a haystack (you're lucky Deusovi got this one so fast!). Also, when what you have encoded bears the appearance of spam advertising users will be quick to downvote! Take a look at other puzzles on this site to get a feel for what is well received :)

Comment: thank you stiv for the suggestions i will look at other puzzles and make a better one this time im kinda just getting a feel for how this works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just several codes chained together:

> decoding with hexadecimal, then with octal, then with binary, gives the text:
>  `Visit 3dprintstogo.com (NOT DONE YET!)`
>  `^`
>  `lol advertising`

Comment: wow that was very fast

Comment: im sad now i ran out of ideas

Comment: Can you add a code snippet as to how to output is obtained?

Comment: honestly you already know this is octal so just use a translator like online